# Improving performance of Python for loops with Pandas data frames

Tags: python, performance, pandas

please consider the following DataFrame df:

```
timestamp    id        condition
             1234      A    
             2323      B
             3843      B
             1234      C
             8574      A
             9483      A
```

Basing on the condition contained in the column condition I have to define a new column in this data frame which counts how many ids are in that condition.
However, please note that since the DataFrame is ordered by the timestamp column, one could have multiple entries of the same id and then a simple .cumsum() is not a viable option.

I have come out with the following code, which is working properly but is extremely slow:

```
#I start defining empty arrays
ids_with_condition_a = np.empty(0)
ids_with_condition_b = np.empty(0)
ids_with_condition_c = np.empty(0)

#Initializing new column
df['count'] = 0

#Using a for loop to do the task, but this is sooo slow!
for r in range(0, df.shape[0]):
    if df.condition[r] == 'A':
        ids_with_condition_a = np.append(ids_with_condition_a, df.id[r])
    elif df.condition[r] == 'B':
        ids_with_condition_b = np.append(ids_with_condition_b, df.id[r])
        ids_with_condition_a = np.setdiff1d(ids_with_condition_a, ids_with_condition_b)
    elifif df.condition[r] == 'C':
        ids_with_condition_c = np.append(ids_with_condition_c, df.id[r])

df.count[r] = ids_with_condition_a.size
```

Keeping these Numpy arrays is very useful to me because it gives the list of the ids in a particular condition. I would also be able to put dinamically these arrays in a corresponding cell in the df DataFrame.

Are you able to come out with a better solution in terms of performance?

Comment: What is expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `groupby` on the column 'condition' and `cumcount` to count how many ids are in each condition up to the current row (which seems to be what your code do):

```
df['count'] = df.groupby('condition').cumcount()+1 # +1 is to start at 1 not 0
```

with your input sample, you get:

```
     id condition  count
0  1234         A      1
1  2323         B      1
2  3843         B      2
3  1234         C      1
4  8574         A      2
5  9483         A      3
```

which is faster than using loop `for`

and if you want just have the row with condition A for example, you can use a mask such as, if you do 
`print (df[df['condition'] == 'A'])`, you see row with only condition egal to A. So to get an array,

```
arr_A = df.loc[df['condition'] == 'A','id'].values
print (arr_A)
array([1234, 8574, 9483])
```

EDIT: to create two column per conditions, you can do for example for condition A:

```
# put 1 in a column where the condition is met
df['nb_cond_A'] = pd.np.where(df['condition'] == 'A',1,None)
# then use cumsum for increment number, ffill to fill the same number down
# where the condition is not meet, fillna(0) for filling other missing values
df['nb_cond_A'] = df['nb_cond_A'].cumsum().ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)
# for the partial list, first create the full array
arr_A = df.loc[df['condition'] == 'A','id'].values
# create the column with apply (here another might exist, but it's one way)
df['partial_arr_A'] = df['nb_cond_A'].apply(lambda x: arr_A[:x])
```

the output looks like this:

```
     id condition  nb_condition_A       partial_arr_A  nb_cond_A
0  1234         A               1              [1234]          1
1  2323         B               1              [1234]          1
2  3843         B               1              [1234]          1
3  1234         C               1              [1234]          1
4  8574         A               2        [1234, 8574]          2
5  9483         A               3  [1234, 8574, 9483]          3
```

then same thing for B, C. Maybe with a loop `for cond in set(df['condition'])` ould be practical for generalisation

EDIT 2: one idea to do what you expalined in the comments but not sure it improves the performance:

```
# array of unique condition
arr_cond = df.condition.unique()
#use apply to create row-wise the list of ids for each condition
df[arr_cond] = (df.apply(lambda row: (df.loc[:row.name].drop_duplicates('id','last')
                                          .groupby('condition').id.apply(list)) ,axis=1)
                  .applymap(lambda x: [] if not isinstance(x,list) else x))
```

Some explanations: for each row, select the dataframe up to this row `loc[:row.name]`, drop the duplicated 'id' and keep the last one `drop_duplicates('id','last')` (in your example, it means that once we reach the row 3, the row 0 is dropped, as the id 1234 is twice), then the data is grouped by condition `groupby('condition')`, and ids for each condition are put in a same list `id.apply(list)`. The part starting with `applymap` fillna with empty list (you can't use fillna([]), it's not possible).

For the length for each condition, you can do:

```
for cond in arr_cond:
    df['len_{}'.format(cond)] = df[cond].str.len().fillna(0).astype(int)
```

THe result is like this:

```
     id condition             A             B       C  len_A  len_B  len_C
0  1234         A        [1234]            []      []      1      0      0
1  2323         B        [1234]        [2323]      []      1      1      0
2  3843         B        [1234]  [2323, 3843]      []      1      2      0
3  1234         C            []  [2323, 3843]  [1234]      0      2      1
4  8574         A        [8574]  [2323, 3843]  [1234]      1      2      1
5  9483         A  [8574, 9483]  [2323, 3843]  [1234]      2      2      1
```

Comment: Hi, I should admit that your solution is pretty elegant, and thank you for improving my knowledge. I would like to understand if it is possible to store arr_A in each row (in a dedicated column) in order to get the list of ids per each timestamp which are meeting a particular condition. To be honest, I'm more interested to the size of this array, I need to keep track of the number of the ids which are changing between one condition to another per timestamp

Comment: @espogian the thing about the timestamp is not really clear to me as in your example there is none (beside the name of the column). Are you saying that the example you give is just for one timestamp, and that you have other timestamps with other several rows of id and conditions?

Comment: Each row has its own timestamp, e.g. one row per second. The purpose is to know, for example at row 3, how many ids meet condition A, how many condition B, etc

Comment: @espogian so to be sure, you would like 2 columns per condition, one with the number of row meeting this condition until the current row (even if this row is not the same condition) and a column with the list of ids meeting this condition until this row?

Comment: The nicest thing which I'm still unable to do would be to have one column per condition with the list of ids meeting that condition so far, and one column per condition with the number of ids meeting that condition so far

Comment: @espogian check my edit if it's the expected output, otherwise I did not understand...

Comment: Thank you, this code is more difficult for me to understand, but I get your point. There is only a missing step: from row 3 onwards, since id 1234 has changed condition, it should not be present in partial_arr_A anymore neither nb_cond_A should count it. That is why I used np.setdiff1d in my code

Comment: Why this thing `np.setdiff1d(df.loc[:, 'arr_A'], df.loc[:, 'arr_B'])` is returning me an error?

Comment: @espogian if you use my code, `arr_A` and `arr_B` are not colums of `df` so it's not possible, but even if you use `partial_arr_A`, it's not going to work (I don't think so). I just notice that you have twice id=1234 and it change of condition (I miss this part, sorry...) I think I understand what you want, I'll try to think about it :)

Comment: I have added another column, `partial_arr_C`, and I'm trying to do the difference betweeen the two arrays `partial_arr_A` and `partial_arr_C` in a third column. But I'm getting ad error. I don't know if there is a Pandas function which is doing this or there is a simpler way. If you find a solution, is more than welcome :) For the moment, thanks again for the support!

Comment: What if I use another DataFrame containing all possible ids (df_ids) and another column with 1 if cond_A is met or 0 if it is not met. And then show in a column in df the sum of all the rows in this new df_ids?

Comment: @espogian not sure I understand what you said in the last comment. Anyway, I tried to give another method, which I hope is the expected result, See my EDIT 2. But not sure it's faster than your original method

Comment: Thank you again, I think your last version is the best one in terms of the output. I can't express any comment about the performance, because my dataset is huge and I'm having a lot of issues in dealing with it, but I think this is the best solution so far!